# TwoDimensionalScrollView in Flutter Not working like SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I'm a bit lost when it comes to the new TwoDimensionalScrollView class in flutter, there doesn't seem to be any examples to go off of right now, and the one I found seems to implement it in the code below, but I'm getting renderflex errors for overflow.  Essentially, I want to set the width and height of the TwoDimensionalScrollView so that I can put this inside other widgets, and just have this little section be scrollable (similar to how I would already use SingelChildScrollView), but I must be missing something:

If you just use this as your main.dart and run, you'll see the error.  Thanks in advance!

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
      // restorationScopeId: restorationID,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SLTTwoDimensionalScrollView(
          mainAxis: Axis.vertical,
          verticalDetails: const ScrollableDetails.vertical(),
          horizontalDetails: const ScrollableDetails.horizontal(),
          diagonalDragBehavior: DiagonalDragBehavior.none,
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          width: 1500,
          height: 34,
          delegate: TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate(
              maxXIndex: 0,
              maxYIndex: 500,
              builder: (BuildContext context, ChildVicinity vicinity) {
                return TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 1500,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 34,
                          width: 500,
                          child: const Text("Filename"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 34,
                          width: 500,
                          child: const Text("Description"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 34,
                          width: 500,
                          child: const Text(
                              "FilePath is the coolest thing we got today and it's good"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SLTTwoDimensionalScrollView extends TwoDimensionalScrollView {
  SLTTwoDimensionalScrollView({
    super.key,
    super.primary,
    super.mainAxis = Axis.vertical,
    super.verticalDetails = const ScrollableDetails.vertical(),
    super.horizontalDetails = const ScrollableDetails.horizontal(),
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.diagonalDragBehavior = DiagonalDragBehavior.none,
    super.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    super.keyboardDismissBehavior = ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.manual,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
    this.height = 34,
    this.width = 500,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  double height;
  double width;

  @override
  Widget buildViewport(BuildContext context, ViewportOffset verticalOffset,
      ViewportOffset horizontalOffset) {
    return SimpleBuilderTableViewport(
      horizontalOffset: horizontalOffset,
      horizontalAxisDirection: horizontalDetails.direction,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      verticalAxisDirection: verticalDetails.direction,
      mainAxis: mainAxis,
      delegate: delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
      height: height,
      width: width,
    );
  }
}

class SimpleBuilderTableViewport extends TwoDimensionalViewport {
  SimpleBuilderTableViewport({
    super.key,
    required super.verticalOffset,
    required super.verticalAxisDirection,
    required super.horizontalOffset,
    required super.horizontalAxisDirection,
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    required super.mainAxis,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
    this.height = 34,
    this.width = 500,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  double height;
  double width;

  @override
  RenderTwoDimensionalViewport createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport(
      horizontalOffset: horizontalOffset,
      horizontalAxisDirection: horizontalAxisDirection,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      verticalAxisDirection: verticalAxisDirection,
      mainAxis: mainAxis,
      delegate: delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate,
      childManager: context as TwoDimensionalChildManager,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
      height: height,
      width: width,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset
      ..horizontalAxisDirection = horizontalAxisDirection
      ..verticalOffset = verticalOffset
      ..verticalAxisDirection = verticalAxisDirection
      ..mainAxis = mainAxis
      ..delegate = delegate
      ..cacheExtent = cacheExtent
      ..clipBehavior = clipBehavior
      ..height = height
      ..width = width;
  }
}

class RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport extends RenderTwoDimensionalViewport {
  RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport({
    required super.horizontalOffset,
    required super.horizontalAxisDirection,
    required super.verticalOffset,
    required super.verticalAxisDirection,
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    required super.mainAxis,
    required super.childManager,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
    this.height = 34,
    this.width = 500,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  RenderBox? testGetChildFor(ChildVicinity vicinity) => getChildFor(vicinity);

  double height;
  double width;

  @override
  void layoutChildSequence() {
    // Really simple table implementation for testing.
    // Every child is 200x200 square
    final double horizontalPixels = horizontalOffset.pixels;
    final double verticalPixels = verticalOffset.pixels;
    final double viewportWidth = viewportDimension.width + cacheExtent;
    final double viewportHeight = viewportDimension.height + cacheExtent;
    final TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate builderDelegate =
        delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate;

    final int maxRowIndex;
    final int maxColumnIndex;
    maxRowIndex = builderDelegate.maxYIndex ?? 5;
    maxColumnIndex = builderDelegate.maxXIndex ?? 5;

    final int leadingColumn = math.max((horizontalPixels / width).floor(), 0);
    final int leadingRow = math.max((verticalPixels / height).floor(), 0);
    final int trailingColumn = math.min(
      ((horizontalPixels + viewportWidth) / width).ceil(),
      maxColumnIndex,
    );
    final int trailingRow = math.min(
      ((verticalPixels + viewportHeight) / height).ceil(),
      maxRowIndex,
    );

    double xLayoutOffset = (leadingColumn * width) - horizontalOffset.pixels;
    for (int column = leadingColumn; column <= trailingColumn; column++) {
      double yLayoutOffset = (leadingRow * height) - verticalOffset.pixels;
      for (int row = leadingRow; row <= trailingRow; row++) {
        final ChildVicinity vicinity =
            ChildVicinity(xIndex: column, yIndex: row);
        final RenderBox child = buildOrObtainChildFor(vicinity)!;
        child.layout(constraints.tighten(width: width, height: height));

        parentDataOf(child).layoutOffset = Offset(xLayoutOffset, yLayoutOffset);
        yLayoutOffset += height;
      }
      xLayoutOffset += width;
    }
    final double verticalExtent = height * (maxRowIndex + 1);
    verticalOffset.applyContentDimensions(
      0.0,
      clampDouble(
          verticalExtent - viewportDimension.height, 0.0, double.infinity),
    );
    final double horizontalExtent = width * (maxColumnIndex + 1);
    horizontalOffset.applyContentDimensions(
      0.0,
      clampDouble(
          horizontalExtent - viewportDimension.width, 0.0, double.infinity),
    );
  }
}
```

I would expect that I set width/height like SingleChildScrollView, and then if the widget inside is bigger, it just works, you can scroll horizontal/vertical and it will scroll over the whole size of the widget inside.

**EDIT!!!**

I made a better question here:
[A row doesn't work inside a TwoDimensionalGridView with 0 maxXIndex in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146815/a-row-doesnt-work-inside-a-twodimensionalgridview-with-0-maxxindex-in-flutter)

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/?id=4424936c57ed13093eb389123383e894

Comment: So if i use that example, but put maxXIndex:0, maxYIndex:500 and try to build a textbutton with a row, i get really weird results.