# A row doesn't work inside a TwoDimensionalGridView with 0 maxXIndex

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to have a set sized TwoDimensionalGridView of 300x300, and Inside that TwoDimensionalGridView I want to have a row that is bigger than that size.  If this was a SingleChildScrollView it would scroll horizontal totally fine with a horizontal axis, but I'm confused how to do that with TwoDimensionalGridView, any suggestions!?

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
        // Mouse dragging enabled for this demo
        dragDevices: PointerDeviceKind.values.toSet(),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 5),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: TwoDimensionalGridView(
//               clipBehavior: Clip.none,<-- change to see difference
              diagonalDragBehavior: DiagonalDragBehavior.free,
              verticalDetails: const ScrollableDetails.vertical(),
              horizontalDetails: const ScrollableDetails.horizontal(),
              delegate: TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate(
                maxXIndex: 0,
                maxYIndex: 9,
                builder: (BuildContext context, ChildVicinity vicinity) {
                  return Row(children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 500,
                      child: Text("Stuff")),
                    Text("More Stuff"),
                    Text("What Not"),
                  ],);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TwoDimensionalGridView extends TwoDimensionalScrollView {
  const TwoDimensionalGridView({
    super.key,
    super.primary,
    super.mainAxis = Axis.vertical,
    super.verticalDetails = const ScrollableDetails.vertical(),
    super.horizontalDetails = const ScrollableDetails.horizontal(),
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.diagonalDragBehavior = DiagonalDragBehavior.none,
    super.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    super.keyboardDismissBehavior = ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.manual,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  @override
  Widget buildViewport(
    BuildContext context,
    ViewportOffset verticalOffset,
    ViewportOffset horizontalOffset,
  ) {
    return TwoDimensionalGridViewport(
      horizontalOffset: horizontalOffset,
      horizontalAxisDirection: horizontalDetails.direction,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      verticalAxisDirection: verticalDetails.direction,
      mainAxis: mainAxis,
      delegate: delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    );
  }
}

class TwoDimensionalGridViewport extends TwoDimensionalViewport {
  const TwoDimensionalGridViewport({
    super.key,
    required super.verticalOffset,
    required super.verticalAxisDirection,
    required super.horizontalOffset,
    required super.horizontalAxisDirection,
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate super.delegate,
    required super.mainAxis,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
  });

  @override
  RenderTwoDimensionalViewport createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderTwoDimensionalGridViewport(
      horizontalOffset: horizontalOffset,
      horizontalAxisDirection: horizontalAxisDirection,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      verticalAxisDirection: verticalAxisDirection,
      mainAxis: mainAxis,
      delegate: delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate,
      childManager: context as TwoDimensionalChildManager,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
    BuildContext context,
    RenderTwoDimensionalGridViewport renderObject,
  ) {
    renderObject
      ..horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset
      ..horizontalAxisDirection = horizontalAxisDirection
      ..verticalOffset = verticalOffset
      ..verticalAxisDirection = verticalAxisDirection
      ..mainAxis = mainAxis
      ..delegate = delegate
      ..cacheExtent = cacheExtent
      ..clipBehavior = clipBehavior;
  }
}

class RenderTwoDimensionalGridViewport extends RenderTwoDimensionalViewport {
  RenderTwoDimensionalGridViewport({
    required super.horizontalOffset,
    required super.horizontalAxisDirection,
    required super.verticalOffset,
    required super.verticalAxisDirection,
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    required super.mainAxis,
    required super.childManager,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  @override
  void layoutChildSequence() {
    final double horizontalPixels = horizontalOffset.pixels;
    final double verticalPixels = verticalOffset.pixels;
    final double viewportWidth = viewportDimension.width + cacheExtent;
    final double viewportHeight = viewportDimension.height + cacheExtent;
    final TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate builderDelegate =
        delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate;

    final int maxRowIndex = builderDelegate.maxYIndex!;
    final int maxColumnIndex = builderDelegate.maxXIndex!;

    final int leadingColumn = math.max((horizontalPixels / 200).floor(), 0);
    final int leadingRow = math.max((verticalPixels / 200).floor(), 0);
    final int trailingColumn = math.min(
      ((horizontalPixels + viewportWidth) / 200).ceil(),
      maxColumnIndex,
    );
    final int trailingRow = math.min(
      ((verticalPixels + viewportHeight) / 200).ceil(),
      maxRowIndex,
    );

    double xLayoutOffset = (leadingColumn * 200) - horizontalOffset.pixels;
    for (int column = leadingColumn; column <= trailingColumn; column++) {
      double yLayoutOffset = (leadingRow * 200) - verticalOffset.pixels;
      for (int row = leadingRow; row <= trailingRow; row++) {
        final ChildVicinity vicinity =
            ChildVicinity(xIndex: column, yIndex: row);
        final RenderBox child = buildOrObtainChildFor(vicinity)!;
        child.layout(
          constraints.loosen(), // <-- the constraints you provide here affect how the child is laid out
        );
        parentDataOf(child).layoutOffset = Offset(xLayoutOffset, yLayoutOffset); // <-- This is where the child is positioned by you in the viewport
        yLayoutOffset += 200;
      }
      xLayoutOffset += 200;
    }

    // Set the min and max scroll extents for each axis.
    final double verticalExtent = 200 * (maxRowIndex + 1);
    verticalOffset.applyContentDimensions(
      0.0,
      clampDouble(
        verticalExtent - viewportDimension.height,
        0.0,
        double.infinity,
      ),
    );
    final double horizontalExtent = 200 * (maxColumnIndex + 1);
    horizontalOffset.applyContentDimensions(
      0.0,
      clampDouble(
        horizontalExtent - viewportDimension.width,
        0.0,
        double.infinity,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried this above code and expect this to work similar to a SingleChildScrollView inside flutter where you can scroll horizontally to see the rest of the row inside this View

Comment: Change item size in RenderTwoDimensionalGridViewport class, bc it's set to 200

Comment: Changing that to 300 doesn't help, still getting renderflex overflowed

Comment: Idk, TwoDimensionalGridView working little bit weird